# Disable changing texture and zooming in UV?

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

In the UV editing room, whenever I select an island, the background texture changes. THATS fine. However this changes the zoom level randomly. Like if I select a UV island, the background texture will change to the texture associated with it and will zoom all the way out or in.

So every selection of a UV island is constant readjusting zoom levels cause the background image keeps changing.

Id like to disable the background image preview all together but I cant find anything. Thus far Ive been using Maya to UV (doesnt have this problem). Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: No bites? Still looking on my own, not finding anything. I cant believe its this hard to just not have the UI fight against me every time I click a UV island.

Answer (score 0):

Check the islands' material, make sure they have the same resolution by plugging in a texture. It should solve the zooming issue.